# AJAX Call Does Not Trigger Action Method When Decorated With CanvasAuthorize

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to share items on Facebook by posting them on the wall via my FB app. I setup everything on the client side and the server side as well (ASP.NET MVC3), but I noticed that when the ActionMethod is decorated with the `CanvasAuthorize` attribute, the method does not get triggered at all. So is there anything I could do?

P.S: I checked the posted data by the AJAX call and everything seemed fine on that end. Moreover, if I comment the `[CanvasAuthorize]` line, the method gets triggered and the params are all fine, except when I get to the `fb.Post()` call, it complains that there is no access_token which makes sense.

```
    //[CanvasAuthorize(Permissions = "publish_stream")]
    public ActionResult PostItem(string message, string link, string picture, string name)
    {
        var fb = new FacebookWebClient();
        var postArgs = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        postArgs["message"] = message;
        postArgs["link"] = link;
        postArgs["picture"] = picture;
        postArgs["name"] = name;
        fb.Post("/me/feed", postArgs);
        return Json(new {result = "success"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Here's a follow-up: [Passing the signed_request along with the AJAX call to an ActionMethod decorated with CanvasAuthorize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071246/passing-the-signed-request-along-with-the-ajax-call-to-an-actionmethod-decorated)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hidden field which you pass with your ajax call.

You can implement this by yourself or use:

```
<%: Html.FacebookSignedRequest() %>
```

Comment: I did that, and then when I inspected it using Firebug here's what I've got (which I've actually expected): `<input id="signed_request" name="signed_request" type="hidden" value=""/>` Any thoughts?